# Adding AMP to wordpress posts with multiple page numbers

Tags: php, wordpress, amp-html

I am working on adding AMP to my wordpress single.php page. I have installed the plugin and am making the edits I need to have it looking correct. The issue I am having is many of my posts are multiple pages and I am trying to figure out how to get wordpress to render the other pages using AMP.

For example if i have a page with the url:

```
www.example.com/post-category/post-title/amp/
```

That would render perfectly using AMP BUT if I try to do:

```
www.example.com/post-category/post-title/2/amp/
```

That redirects to a different post instead of going to the second page of the intended post. If anyone has any idea of how to make this work as it should I would be very grateful. This is the last part I have to figure out to get my pages to work with AMP.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the URL(s) about which you are asking for help. It's difficult to imagine what might be going on.

Comment: improved url formatting